# Git merge of remote branch reports “Already up-to-date” when there are new remote commits

Tags: git, merge

We regularly run this merge:

```
git merge origin/feature-branch
```

It seems there is a lag where I can see the commit in feature-branch (using BitBucket) but the merge command returns `Already up-to-date.`.   We have to wait around 10 minutes after the commit to successfully run the merge.  Is there some cache that needs to be cleared to get the latest without waiting?

---

*Update*:

The solution is described below.  Turns out there wasn't really any "lag" or cache.  I guess in the past I sometimes ran `git pull` in between unsuccessful and successful merge attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution here was to run `git pull` first:

```
git pull
git merge origin/feature-branch
```

This [blog post](http://jamesjoshuahill.github.io/note/2015/02/07/is-your-branch-up-to-date/) sorted me out.  I had no idea that:

> You may not have realised that git keeps a clone of your remote
>   repositories on your machine ... `origin/master` is not
>   on GitHub, it’s the clone of the remote master branch on your machine.

Thus had to do the git pull to update my "local" clone of origin/master.   Then the merged worked!

Comment: Note that pull already does a merge (of the configured remote-tracking branch). If you don’t want that, use `git fetch` instead of `git pull`.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout feature-branch
git pull
git checkout Your-Branch
git merge feature-branch
```

If someone else is also working on your branch then

```
git pull Your-Branch
git checkout feature-branch
git pull
git merge feature-branch
```